# Default constructor is being called with no reference to it

Tags: c++, class, constructor, default-constructor, ctor-initializer

why the following code won't work:

```
#include <iostream>

class Entity
{
public:
    /*
    Entity()
    {
        std::cout << "Create Entity with default constructor" << std::endl;
    }
     */

    Entity(int x)
    {
        std::cout << "Create Entity with " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

class Example
{
    Entity ent;
    int age;

public:
    Example()
            //: ent(7), age(7)
    {
        ent=Entity(7);
        age=7;
    }
};

int main() {
    Example s1;
    return 0;
}
```

it says that it need default constructor for Entity but why is that? the only Entity object I'm using is built using the constructor that uses 1 argument.

Plus, why changing `Example s1;` to         `Example s1();` will cause my code to work in different way (I can't see any printings on the screen.

Comment: Because you commented out the initialiser list, `: ent(7), age(7)`.

Comment: `Example s1();` declares a function called s1 that takes no parameters and returns an Example object.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `Example` constructor, the member variable `ent` already needs to be constructed. It's this construction that is meant by the error.

The solution is to use a constructor initializer list, which you have commented out in the example shown.

---

As for

```
Example s1();
```

That declares `s1` as a function that takes no arguments and returns an `Example` object by value.

Comment: But why? I am giving ent its value at the same time, why it needs to be constructed with the default constructor first.

Comment: @smith Because that’s how C++ works. By the time the constructor body is entered, all member objects are *already* constructed.

Comment: @smith Assignment and initialization are two different things. Inside the constructror body you only do *assignment* to an already constructed and initialized object. It's no different from having a global variable `Entity ent;` and then assigning to that in any function.

Answer (score 1):

Within the body of this constructor

```
Example()
        //: ent(7), age(7)
{
    ent=Entity(7);
    age=7;
}
```

the data member `ent` that is used in the assignment statement (in assignment operators can be used already constructed objects)

```
    ent=Entity(7);
```

must be already constructed. However it can not be constructed using the default constructor that is absent. This expression `Entity( 7 )`  does not create the object `ent`. It creates a temporary object that is assigned to `ent` by using the default copy assignment operator implicitly defined by the compiler.

You have to write at least

```
Example() : ent(7), age(7)
{
}
```

specifying explicitly the called constructor with parameter in the mem-initializer list of the constructor of the class `Example`. In this case the data member `ent` will be created using this constructor before the control will be passed to the body of the constructor of the class `Example`.

Comment: But why? I am giving ent its value at the same time, why it needs to be constructed with the default constructor first.

Comment: @smith Where are you giving a value? In the assignment statement when the object shall be already created? Within the body of a constructor you are dealing with already created data members.

Comment: why I need to create ent before I assign a value to it? for example take int x=10; it doesn't create x with 0 then give it 10.

Comment: @smith There is a difference between int x = 10; and int x; x = 10; In the first case the object x is created and initialized. In the second case the object at first created and then a value is assigned to the already created object. How can you assign a value for something that was not yer created?!

Answer (score 0):

When you explicitly define any constructor, the implicitly defined default constructor is deleted and is not available for use.

When you don't initialize a member explicitly using initialization list syntax in a constructor, the default constructor is used to initilize it.

```
Example()
{
    ent=Entity(7);
    age=7;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Example() : ent(), age()
{
    ent=Entity(7);
    age=7;
}
```

That explains the compiler error. To fix the error, use

```
Example() : ent(7), age(7)
{
}
```

Comment: But why? I am giving ent its value at the same time, why it needs to be constructed with the default constructor first.

Comment: That behavior is defined by the standard. Take a look at the section of the standard that talks about [Initializing bases and members](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.base.init).